# Is it possible to communicate between ethereum smart contract and binance smart chain contract?

Tags: mainnet, cross-chain

I would like to call a function in the Binance smart chain contract from my ethereum mainnet smart contract is this possible?

Comment: You can make a bridge between both with Web3.js and Node.js

Answer (score 1):

No. That's not possible directly.

Both blockchains are deterministic (as all blockchain are, typically). That means that the blockchain can only use data which it has inside it - it can't use data from outside the blockchain, unless someone provides the data in a transaction.

Various types of oracles can be used to communicate with external systems. So you could build an oracle which communicates even between these two blockchains, but the oracle would probably be quite centralized (you would control it, so users would need to trust it).